# GCD vs custom queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I was wondering what is the difference in performance between these two.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

    // perform complex operation

    // dispatch back to main thread to update UI

});



dispatch_async(_myCustomConcurrentQueue, ^{

    // perform complex operation

    // dispatch back to main thread to update UI

});
```

My assumption is the GCD is used across the os and other applications, and it will need to perform very quick background tasks, and be finished quick. And custom queues that are created are separate from GCD and they can run a different task, and will be added back to the pool once they are released. And so my assumption is that my customQueue performs better than GCD for a complex operation.

What are your thoughts? Which performs better? Are they the same?

Comment: Not a full answer, because I don't have the time to go dig for the documentation references, but: those two calls are almost certainly equivalent. Choice of queue is more about how the blocks are scheduled relative to other blocks on the same queue (or other global concurrent queues). Chances are, they end up executing on the same underlying GCD thread either way.

Comment: A "custom queue" _is_ a GCD queue. It's the same system

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the high-priority global queue might theoretically be faster (since you don't have to create the queue, slightly different thread priority), the difference between that and your own custom concurrent queue is unlikely to be observable. There are two reasons, though, that you might want to use your own custom queues:

1. Certain features, notably dispatch barriers, are unavailable in global queues, so if you need those features, you'll want to use custom queue.
2. Debugging your app, it can also be useful to use your own queues with meaningful names, so that you can more easily identify the individual threads in the debugger.

But there are no material performance reasons to choose high priority global concurrent queue vs a custom concurrent queue.

Comment: It all depends on the priority band of the global concurrent queue he uses.  There can be a significant difference between HIGH and BACKGROUND, for example, and not just due to the fact that GCD will execute things in the HIGH queue first - the thread priorities are also set differently for the worker threads used to do the work.

Comment: @jhk Good clarification. The question was about the difference between high priority global queue and custom concurrent queue, so I assume the OP was trying to take the lower priority global queues out of the discussion, but you're quite right that both the order of the global queues and their relative priorities can come into play. I still contend, though, that for most apps the difference between the high priority global queue and a custom concurrent will not generally be observable. Still, I tried to clarify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't say how _myCustomConcurrentQueue was created (it could be a serial queue or a concurrent queue), but assuming that it's a concurrent queue then it will have potentially a different priority than the global concurrent queues, both in terms of how GCD dispatches blocks or functions from its internal "queue of queues" blocklist and in the actual thread priority of the thread(s) created to do the work!

Please read the dispatch_queue_create(3) man page and pay specific attention to the "GLOBAL CONCURRENT QUEUES" section.  It contains some very informative verbiage on this exact topic (too much to cut-and-paste here).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that if you create your own queue, it ultimately gets added to the GCD behind the scenes. I guess it's more of a preference thing.