# Concurrency issue when dividing up recursive task

Tags: swift, recursion, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I am dealing with geometric types that can be subdivided into instances of themselves. This capability is expressed by the following protocol:

```
protocol Subdividable {
    func subdivision(using block: (Self) -> ())
}
```

An implementation of `Subdividable` might look something like this:

```
struct Tile { ... }

extension Tile: Subdividable {
    func subdivision(using block: (Tile) -> ()) {
        if condition() {
            let (a, b) = createSubTiles()
            block(a)
            block(b)
        } else {
            let (a, b, c) = createDifferentSubTiles()
            block(a)
            block(b)
            block(c)
        }
    }
}
```

The number of instances a given type subdivides into is not fixed and may or may not depend on properties of the subdivided instance. Once created, every new instance is passed to `block`.

To create the final result, I need to apply such subdivisions recursively a given number of times:

```
extension Subdividable {
    func subdivision(level: Int, using block: (Self) -> ()) {
        switch level {
        case 0:
            return
        case 1:
            subdivision(using: block)
        default:
            precondition(level > 1)
            subdivision { value in
                value.subdivision(level: level - 1, using: block)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As it can't generally be predicted from the onset, how many times `block` will be called, it is also necessary to keep track of an index. (i.e. to store the result in a buffer)

```
extension Subdividable {
    @discardableResult func subdivision(level: Int, using block: (Int, Self) -> ()) -> Int {
        var result = 0

        subdivision(level: level) { value in
            block(result, value)

            result += 1
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

So far, so good. The resulting geometries can be very complex and may consist of several million elements, making performance a concern. That's why I tried to divide the recursive subdivision into multiple concurrent tasks, it does however not reliably accumulate the results from each of those:

```
extension Subdividable {
    @discardableResult func subdivision(level: (lhs: Int, rhs: Int), using block: @escaping (Self) -> (Int, Self) -> ()) -> Int {
        var result = 0

        let (queue, group) = (DispatchQueue.global(), DispatchGroup())

        subdivision(level: level.lhs) { value in
            queue.async(group: group) {
                let count = value.subdivision(level: level.rhs, using: block(value))

                // not all barrier tasks will have finished after group.wait()
                queue.async(group: group, flags: .barrier) {
                    result += count // accumulate result
                }
            }
        }

        group.wait()

        return result
    }
}
```

Why does waiting on the `group` not guarantee the inner `async` calls to be finished?

I have also tried implementing the above function with a custom serial queue to push the accumulation block onto, and that works, always giving the correct result. I just don't understand why that's not equivalent to pushing it onto the concurrent queue as a barrier task.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to implement this without requiring a custom queue?

**Edit No. 1**

The issue doesn't seem to be the `group` not waiting properly but rather the global queue dropping items. Changing `queue` from `DispatchQueue.global()` to `DispatchQueue(label: "subdivision", attributes: .concurrent)` results in correct behavior.

I also ended up wrapping the entire function body in `withoutActuallyEscaping(block) { block in ... }` so that the input closure doesn't need to be `@escaping`, which did not result in a crash when using the global queue, which it would have if there actually were tasks executing after `group.wait()`. To me this reads as the global queue silently dropping items for whatever reason, right?

How can this be and why does a custom concurrent queue not show the same behavior?

**Edit No. 2**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22030777/2958214) barriers just aren't supported on global queues. They seem to be happy to accept them but then ignore the flag, running the tasks concurrently, resulting in undefined behavior.

I can't find this being properly documented anywhere, does anybody have some pointers?